# If certain URLs loaded, then interrupt not working

Tags: android, webview

I've got a `webview`, and it posts a login string, changes view, then loads the page:

```
    String url = uurrll;
            mWebview .postUrl(url, EncodingUtils.getBytes(fullpost, "BASE64"));
            mWebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                    if(url.contains("/logout")) {
                        view.stopLoading();
                        setContentView(R.layout.preweb);
                        addListenerOnButton();
                        return true;
                    }
                    if(url.contains("/loginf")) {
                        view.stopLoading();
                        setContentView(R.layout.preweb);
                        addListenerOnButton();
                        return true;
                    }
                    else {
                        return false;
                    }
                }

            });
```

And within that, I'd like to constantly monitor what URL is being loaded.  If a user clicks a hyperlink within the page and the url contains a certain pattern, I want to stop the loading and redirect to whatever.  The above code is just an example of what I've got in there for testing right now.

I can't get it working.  If a URL pops up that has "loginf" in it, nothing happens at all.  I've tried moving the `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` to different parts in my code, but it doesn't work anywhere.

Any advice, or am I going about this completely wrong?

EDIT:  I believe this is because the new URL that the webpage is calling is through Javascript.  How do I read/interrupt the URL request when its coming from Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

I think the key is `setContentView(R.layout.preweb);`, you use it in `new WebViewClient()`

If you want to redirect to another url , use `mWebview.postUrl();`

If you want to show other layout, use `XXActivity.this.setContentView(R.layout.preweb);`

[Debug UI GUIDE](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-ui.html)

now, the tool locates at `$ANDROID_HOME/tools/monitor`

Comment: Well, now it's not loading the page (which is good) but it's just a blank white screen.  EDIT:  Nope, still loading the page.  I just temporarily lost my DNS.  So, yeah, that didn't work :(

Comment: @IAmTheSquidward is the layout(R.layout.preweb) blank? A suggestion is monitoring the views (UI DEBUG)[http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-ui.html]

Comment: It's not blank, I can call the layout at any other point and it loads fine.  It's still loading the URL.

Comment: I see that `ShouldOverrideUrlLoading` doesn't work with Javascript URL changes.  That's how my page is changing.  Is there another method that I don't know about?

Comment: @IAmTheSquidward If you could write js code in `/loginf`, you can call android method [http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html#UsingJavaScript]